# A function to compare two select option php :

Tags: php, select

I need help with a function to compare two select option php:

Example :

```
<?PHP
    function generateSelectFromArray($array){ 
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option class='form-control' value='$key'> $value </option>";
   }
}

$example = array(
 0=>"fara",
 1=>"example",
);

$attrtype0=$_POST['attrtype0'];
$attrtype1=$_POST['attrtype1'];
$attrvalue0=$_POST['attrvalue0'];
$attrvalue1=$_POST['attrvalue1'];    

?>

<h3>Bonus #1</h3>
<select name="attrtype0" class="form-control"><?php generateSelectFromArray($example); ?> </select>
<h3>Bonus #2</h3>
<select name="attrtype1" class="form-control"><?php generateSelectFromArray($example); ?> </select>
```

Problem 1 is : If option value attrtype0 is 1 and option value attrtype1 is 1 make a error example echo'Duplicate select .';

Problem 2 is : If option value attrtype0 is 1 attrvalue0 recive value 12 of example .

No speak good english but I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand you need to do like below (modification and changes are stated through comments):-

```
<?PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL); // get all type of error including warning and notice too
ini_set('display_errors',1); // display those errors
$example = array(0=>"fara",1=>"example");
function generateSelectFromArray($array){ 
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option class='form-control' value='$key'> $value </option>";
   }
}
?>
<form method = "POST"> <!-- create a form to post your data -->
<h3>Bonus #1</h3>
<select name="attrtype0" class="form-control"><?php generateSelectFromArray($example); ?> </select>
<h3>Bonus #2</h3>
<select name="attrtype1" class="form-control"><?php generateSelectFromArray($example); ?> </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value = "send data"> <!-- create button to submit form -->
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['attrtype0']) && isset($_POST['attrtype1'])){ // check bothe select box values are coming or not?
    if($_POST['attrtype0'] === $_POST['attrtype1']){ // check same values are selected or not
         echo "duplicate selected";
    }else{
        echo "values are different";
    }

}
?>
```